# Escape angle brackets with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, escaping

*Question was totally rewrited in more compact and clear form.*

When I write HTML documents with snippets inside, I don't want to manually change every `<` to `&lt;`. The most obvious way, from my point of view, was to use JS for this task, as shown below. However, it doesn't work.

How it may be fixed?

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tfz9wgj8/4/)**

```
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            width: 500px;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        window.onload = function() {
            var pre = document.querySelector("#html-example");
            pre.innerHTML = pre.innerHTML
                .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
                .replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>
        Chapter 1
    </h1>
    <p>
        Here is the first tutorial of HTML for total beginners.
        Typical HTML contains of 2 main parts: head and body.
        Here is an exmaple of how it looks:
    </p>
    <pre id="html-example" style="background-color: aliceblue;">
<head>
    Head content goes here. Only very technical things
</head>
<body>
    Body content goes here. Not necessary very technical.
    For example, something about cats.
</body>
    </pre>
    <p>
        ..............
    </p>
</body>
```

> Current result:

[image]

> Desired result:

[image]

Comment: *“I want to understand how negligence of script-way may be fixed.”* It can’t; don’t do it. It’s completely unsafe and there’s no good reason for it.

Comment: @Ryan Ok, but how I can accomplish my task? I have static HTML documents, in which I write articles about HTML and JS for my personal local use. Obviously, these articles contain HTML snippets and it's descriptions. Is there a way to write it, except of manually replace every `<`? If there is no JS-way, then OK, maybe I should install some simple server and it would be escaped with PHP or another server-side language? Here at StackOverflow we write a lot of snippets without esaping, and all this code successfully and safely posted on the web.

Comment: Stack Overflow uses Markdown; you can do that too if you want, using a static site generator like [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/).

Comment: Well, OK, I understand about Markdown. But there are also another sites and forums about programming, and sometimes they are don't use Markdown. Despite of it, the code, which users post on these sites is still successfully escaped. If I can't (or should not) accomplish it with JS, I would to know how it could be implemented generally, in most cases.

Comment: With dynamic server-side rendering, yes, or by pre-rendering like the aforementioned static site generators (which seems appropriate for your case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is totally not the best way to do this, but I think it's better than doing a find/replace on `<>` and definitely beats any solution that relies on HTML parsing in javascript (never do that...).

In the HTML documents you write, you could include code examples using a `<script type="text/html">` tag instead of the `<pre>` tag that you're using now.

By default, the browser doesn't really do anything with this type of tag. But in javascript, you can select it like any other element using `document.querySelector` or any other DOM api method.

This means that on document load, you can replace all the `<script>` tags by `<pre>` tags with a text node:

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".js-example"))
  .forEach(el => {
    const textNode = document.createTextNode(el.innerHTML)
    const pre = document.createElement("pre");

    pre.style.backgroundColor = "aliceblue";
    pre.appendChild(textNode);

    el.parentElement.insertBefore(pre, el);
    el.parentElement.removeChild(el);

  })
```

```html
<h1>
  Chapter 1
</h1>
<p>
  Here is the first tutorial of HTML for total beginners. Typical HTML contains of 2 main parts: head and body. Here is an exmaple of how it looks:
</p>

<script class="js-example" type="text/html">
<head>
  Head content goes here. Only very technical things
</head>

<body>
  Body content goes here. Not necessary very technical. For example, something about cats.
</body>
</script>

<p>
  ..............
</p>

<p>
  Another example:
  <script class="js-example" type="text/html">
An unclosed tag: </p>
  </script>
...
</p>
```

Disclaimer: I'd use this only for simple examples... If it's the main goal of your website I'd invest in a more elegant solution like mentioned in the comments. Also, I don't think this solution support examples that contain their own `</script>` tags...

Comment: Thank you :-) But why simple JS-replacements, like shown in my example, doesn't work properly?

Comment: Your function executes `onload`, which means it starts running *after* the browser has parsed your HTML. A `<pre>` tag holds *preformatted* text, but that doesn't mean the browser ignores any HTML markup inside it. E.g.: If you do `<pre><strong>Hello</strong></pre>` it will still be **bold**. When the browser parses the `<pre>`'s contents, it removes any HTML markup, which means there are no `<` characters left when your javascript method kicks in.